# Symfony 2 ScannerException @(64)

Tags: symfony, yaml

I'm getting following exception in my app/config/config.yml file:

> ScannerException while scanning for the next token we had this found
>   character @(64) that cannot start any token

The line that causes exception:`- { resource: @BazaBlogBundle/Resources/config/config.yml }`

I think it's compatibility problem. I'm following tutorial for Symfony version 2.0 and I'm using 2.16. Any thoughts?

Comment: Scanner is outdated and buggy. I hope Netbeans fixes it

Comment: Seems to be a Netbeans bug to be fixed in 7.4: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=232192

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are missing the double quotes :

```
- { resource: "@BazaBlogBundle/Resources/config/config.yml" }
```